# Changing/adding CSS classes based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to get a site to show and potentially sell my artwork, and need some help with a page header and menu (both in the same div), which at the top of the page are angled by 45° and are above the other elements (at z-index 2).  This is fine at a scroll position of 0, but gets in the way when one scrolls down to the page's other text elements, and non-background images.  I want to have these elements to be moved to 0 rotation, and fixed at the top of the page at any scroll position >300px, or even duplicate them and have one show and the other hide based upon this position.  I can do the CSS part myself, but scripting is a bit beyond me.

I already have tried this (https://css-tricks.com/styling-based-on-scroll-position/ ) to change the CSS, but haven't had any luck getting it to do anything.  The menu itself is shown/hidden through another piece of javascript that does work.  Both the scripts I have tried, and the CSS are linked externally.

This is the current code I have:
html:

```
<div class="bgimg-1">
</div>
<div class="base">
<h2>Site Name</h2>
<div>
<h3><a href="#" onclick="siteMenu()" class="dropbtn">Menu</a></h3>
</div>
<ul class="menu" id="content">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="design.html">Design Services</a></li>
<li><a href="print.html">Artwork</a></li>
<li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.base {
position: fixed;
top: 11rem;
left: -4rem;
width: 100%;
z-index: 2;
}

.base h2 {

width: 35%;
background: #000000;
padding: .25rem 1rem .25rem 3rem;
color: #FFFFFF;
transform: rotate(45deg);
font-family: novecento-sans-wide, sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
}

.base h3 {
width: 20%;
transform: rotate(45deg);
background: #000000;
padding: .25rem 2rem .25rem 3rem;
margin-left: 3rem;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: novecento-sans-wide, sans-serif;
font-weight: 500;
}

.base a {
 text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF; 
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to do that at a fixed scroll position of 300px rather than when a particular part of you page comes into view? Because on different devices the user experience will differ. Instead could you consider Intersection Observer?

Comment: You're right.  It was arbitrary, and something that I should have used something resolution independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery for the detection on 300px and adding a class. Just to make it funky for you I added a `transition:all 1s;`. Since you know your CSS, enjoy with a simply added class. Cheers!

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if($(document).scrollTop() >= 300 ) {
    $('.base h2').addClass('rotateback');
    $('.base h3').addClass('rotateback');
  } else {
    $('.base h2').removeClass('rotateback');
    $('.base h3').removeClass('rotateback');
  }
});
```

```css
body{
height:2000px;
}
.base {
position: fixed;
top: 11rem ; /* 11rem */
left: -4rem;
width: 100%;
z-index: 2;
}

.base h2 {
width: 35%;
background: #000000;
padding: .25rem 1rem .25rem 3rem;
color: #FFFFFF;
transform: rotate(45deg);
font-family: novecento-sans-wide, sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
transition:all 1s;
}

.base h3 {
width: 20%;
transform: rotate(45deg);
background: #000000;
padding: .25rem 2rem .25rem 3rem;
margin-left: 3rem;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: novecento-sans-wide, sans-serif;
font-weight: 500;
transition:all 1s;
}

.base a {
 text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF; 
}

.base h2.rotateback {
   transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.base h3.rotateback {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bgimg-1">
</div>
<div class="base">
<h2>Site Name</h2>
<div>
<h3><a href="#" onclick="siteMenu()" class="dropbtn">Menu</a></h3>
</div>
<ul class="menu" id="content">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="design.html">Design Services</a></li>
<li><a href="print.html">Artwork</a></li>
<li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!

I couldn't edit, so I deleted my earlier reply.  Works perfectly!  Although I now have to tweak positioning in the new class, particularly for certain resolutions, that's going to be mindlessly easy to do.